# Using grids from a different script

Tags: unity, c#

I suspect there is a very simple answer to this one but I have been scratching my head trying to figure it out for a while.

I have this piece of code that works fine. It effectively adds the location of the children of my GameObject to a grid array.

```
  public void AddToGrid()
       {
        Transform[,] grid = new Transform[totalGridWidth, totalGridHeight];
        foreach (Transform children in transform)
           {
               int roundedX = Mathf.RoundToInt(children.transform.position.x);
               int roundedY = Mathf.RoundToInt(children.transform.position.y);
               grid[roundedX, roundedY] = children;

           }
       }
```

However, I need to modify it so that rather than taking the children of the GameObject that runs this script - I need it of the children of a different GameObject.

i.e. this script sits on GameObject A, however I need to change it to grab the position of the children on GameObject B. I don't want to simply add this script also to B as there is other stuff in the script that won't make any sense and I need to keep the array in A.

I suspect (hope) there is an easy answer here, but am struggling to figure it out.
Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Have you considered passing in the second object as an argument to the method? Or, does this second object have any defining characteristics by which we can locate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's an easy way. See how in line 4 above you are using the lowercase transform? That is a shortcut in the Monobehavior class that is a convenience to give you a reference to the transform of the GameObject you are located on.

The equivalent more-explicit line would be:

```
foreach (Transform children in this.transform)
```

So what you actually want to do, inspect the transform and hence the children of ANOTHER game object, coincidentally that very same "transform" shortcut exists on a GameObject as well, also as a convenience.

If you declare a public GameObject, like so:

```
public GameObject TheOtherThingIWannaGetChildrenFrom;
```

And drag the target object into that field in your inspector, then you can recode line 4 above to do it to that new object, like so:

```
foreach (Transform children in TheOtherThingIWannaGetChildrenFrom.transform)
```

You could also modify the function to accept an arbitrary GameObject and operate on it that way.

That entire mechanism is kind of how scripts and GameObjects and Transforms and hierarchies and everything is connected up in Unity, so check it out and jump right in!